# Subset a data frame constructed from reactive expressions

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having issues with shiny. I have a number of inputs that I'm collating into lists. I'm then using `cbind()` to combine these into a data frame.

What I now want to do is remove all rows of this data frame that have no value in the first column.

within shinyServer

```
exposure.df <- reactive({as.data.frame(cbind("Exposure" = exposure.vector(), "NDF?" = exposure.ndf.vector(), "Source" = exposure.source.vector(), "Time" = exposure.time.vector(), "Weight" = exposure.weight.vector()))})
```

when I try to subset it:

```
exposure.df <- reactive({subset(exposure.df(), !(Exposure == ""))})
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>   No stack trace available

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a reactive `exposure.df` and then you are trying to have it react on itself in the second line, thus the recursion. You could put multiple lines within the definition of `exposure.df`:

```
exposure.df <- reactive({
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind("Exposure" = exposure.vector(), "NDF?" = exposure.ndf.vector(), "Source" = exposure.source.vector(), "Time" = exposure.time.vector(), "Weight" = exposure.weight.vector()))
    subset(df, !(Exposure == ""))
})
```

Then the result of the last operation (in this case, `subset`) is what you get when you call the reactive `exposure.df()`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.